# Creating lightning bolt effects

Tags: c#, memory-management

Which one of these are better for the memory?

```
protected static List<Line> CreateBolt(Vector2 source, Vector2 dest, float thickness)
{
    //...

    for (int i = 1; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        float pos = positions[i];
        float scale = (length * Jaggedness) * (pos - positions[i - 1]);
        float envelope = pos > 0.95f ? 20 * (1 - pos) : 1;
        float displacement = Rand(-Sway, Sway);
        displacement -= (displacement - prevDisplacement) * (1 - scale);

        // ,,,
    }
    //...
}
```

```
protected static List<Line> CreateBolt(Vector2 source, Vector2 dest, float thickness)
{
    //...
    float pos;
    float scale;
    float envelope;
    float displacement;     

    for (int i = 1; i < positions.Count; i++)
    {
        pos = positions[i];
        scale = (length * Jaggedness) * (pos - positions[i - 1]);
        envelope = pos > 0.95f ? 20 * (1 - pos) : 1;
        displacement = Rand(-Sway, Sway);
        displacement -= (displacement - prevDisplacement) * (1 - scale);

        // ,,,
    }
    //...
}
```

Should I declare variables before or inside a `for loop`? Does it even make a difference at all?

Comment: It is premature optimization either way.  You should keep your variables in as tight a scope as possible, so the first one is correct.

Comment: @Hosch250 can i ask what you mean by premature optimization ? not sure if its a term or if my English is poor. The reason i ask this question is because i think that on the first example new variables are constantly created and deleted, whereas in the second example, variables are created and deleted only once therefore the second example is better. Is that not the case ?

Comment: It means you are trying to optimize your code for memory usage when it is not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your versions will probably generate the same IL code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383090/2655508

The first version is still better, because you should declare variables as near as possible to their usage.

---

You shouldn't shorten variable names. You already have `positions[]` so why do you have `pos` instead of `position`?

---

You have some magic numbers in your code which should be extracted to some constants with meaningful names.

Comment: Yes, no magic numbers.

Comment: "you should declare variables as near as possible to their usage" doesn't that mean that the first is better ?

Comment: @Shiro, typing without looking ;-) Updated answer

Comment: thanks, really helpful stackoverflow post you got there, interesting

Answer (score 3):

I personally would use the second one. The first one creates, assigns, and  destroys `.Count` times, whereas the second one, creates 1 time, assigns `.Count` times, and destroys one time.

Now the compiler *might* optimize that out, but it also might not.

The first one does have the benefit of keeping everything a bit more contained, but I'm gussing that after the loop, there isn't much more to do anyways, so those variables won't still exist for very long anyways.

Comment: yes, as Heslacher said above, it appears that compilers usually optimize these things out for you. if you look at the post he linked, the generated IL code is actually exactly the same. good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

First approach:

- Localizing the scope of the variable.
- Maintainability

Second approach:

- Performance (though insignificant) because of allocation and initialization.
- Object creation and destruction for each run of the loop.

A good read: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/08/21/declare-variables-inside-or-outside-loop

Slight optimisation:

```
  (length * Jaggedness) // Extract it out of the loop into a constant or temp variable.

  float displacement = Rand(-Sway, Sway); // out of the loop.
```

This will surely add a more calculable difference in latency than the above approaches :)